# Same script on multiple objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that controlls the movement of 4 NPCs. Each NPC navigates through the scene and arrives at a specific destination based on the passage order that each NPC passed through a control object.

Here is the destinations manager code (just the important bits)

```
public class DestinationsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    NPCNav navInstance;
    public int destID;

    void Start()
    {
        navInstance = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("npc").GetComponent<NPCNav>();
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider hit)
    {
        if(hit.CompareTag("npc"))
        {
            int npcNewDest = destID;
            navInstance.SetDestNPC(npcNewDest);
        }
    }

}
```

destID is set manually through the editor for each destination object.

And the NPC navigation script (again, only the important bits)

```
public class NPCNav : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int npcID;
    public GameObject passageControlObject;
    public List<GameObject> destinations;
    private NavMeshAgent theAgent;
    private Animator animator;
    private int npcAtDest = -1;
    
    void Start()
    {
        theAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void SetDestNPC(int npcdest)
    {
        npcAtDest = npcdest;
    }
}
```

npcID is set manually through the editor for each NPC and npcAtDest=-1 shows that a NPC has not arrived to a destination.

My problem is on `DestinationsManager` at `Start()` when initializing the navInstance, it initializes the instance for the NPC with ID=0. Just like that, when another NPC arrives at a destination, the NPC with ID=0 gets all the updates. I want to update the `npcAtDest` for each NPC, kinda like having one `navInstance` for each NPC. For example, the NPC with ID=2 arrives at destination 1, only the `npcAtDest` for this NPC changes value to 1 (instead of -1). All the other NPCs have `npcAtDest=-1` if they did not arrive to a destination, or equal to the ID of the corresponding destination.

I am not sure what to do. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: so, the destination manager is on each lets call it waypoint, well each of those need unique IDs then which your class allows for. if you dont set it, it will default to 0 and they will head to default 0.  Surely your destination manager should hold the way points not the npc nav? then it hands back where the next destination is?  What would be awkward is that the destination manager could end up different on each way point.  You need to break it to a waypoint manager, a way point which says you got here, asks manager for new pos, and npc that accepts new pos

Comment: In the OnTriggerEnter, you are using some random navInstance (the random one you found in Start) and not the one that entered the trigger.

Comment: @BugFinder Correct, each destination-waypoint has its own ID which I set on the editor. All NPCs go the correct destination based on the passage order as I described. On the NPCNav I instruct each NPC based on some conditions to go to a specific destination. Problem is, that destination value is pretty much lost afterwards. I will try something and let will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from the use of a random NPC in the destination script.  DestinationManager finds a random NPC during Start, then when any npc enters the trigger, destination manager uses the npc it found during Start instead of the one that entered the trigger.

Instead you should be assigning the new destination on the npc that entered the trigger.

```
public class DestinationsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int destID;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider hit)
    {
        if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent<NPCNav>(out NPCNav navInstance))
        {
            navInstance.SetDestNPC(destID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that and give you an update in some time. Thank you for your time